# Find path to active user directory in C

Tags: c#, c, windows

I'm writing a C# program where I have to write some files to a temp folder. In this program, I call an executable from a C project which also needs to write to said temp folder. In `C#`, I can simply find this with

```
Directory.GetTempPath();
```

But in `C`, I can't seem to find any way of locating it. Do I need to rewrite the C program to take the path as an argument? I would really prefer not to since I'm not very proficient in the language and only barely got it working for my current purpose.

Are there any other, static locations in Windows where it would be appropriate to write temporary files?

Comment: In C you have access to the [native file API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-management-functions), including `GetTempPath()`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to declare the file name relative to a system variable, like `%temp%` and create there your file as standard file (maybe with a pattern so you can delete it at end of your need), there's also `F* tempfile()` [library function](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Temporary-Files.html), but I used it only on linux and don't know if it works on windows (it returns you a pointer to a system-defined temp file)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar function GetTempPath in Win32 API - `GetTempPathA` [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppatha)

You can see how most of C# code is implemented using ReferenceSource. For the `GetTempPath()` function it calls Win32 API [directly.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,3a7a8c72321c6e1d)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've got something to the tune off:

    char buff[256];
    GetTempPath(200,buff);
    strcat(buff,"folder_in_tmp\\tmpfile.txt");
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(buff, "w");

However, I can't build when i #include <fileapi.h>. It gives a bunch of errors, starting with "Identifier "PCONTEXT" is unidentified. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I haven't been programming C/C++ for a while, can't tell for sure. But to start with you can try official MSDN example. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/creating-and-using-a-temporary-file